# How to disable CORS for a host in Spring security

Tags: java, spring

How can I insert into this piece of code so that for the host http://localhost:5173, it was disabled?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

I added this bean, but it didn't help:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/app/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173");
            }
        };
    }
```